# Poincaré inequality for connected Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a compactly generated second countable locally compact group, and let $\mu$ be a probability measure which is:

- symmetric,
- adapted (in the sense that there is no proper subgroup $H$ such that $\mu(H)=1$),
- supported on a compact generating set of $G$,
- absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Haar measure on $G$.

Is there a "Poincaré inequality" for this settings?

If not, maybe for connected Lie group $G$?

Comment: Which kind of Poincaré inequality do you mean? A "local" Poincaré inequality (on balls)? A $L^2$ Poincaré inequality with the variance? Can you please write it?

Comment: Yes, a local one. Of course, one would have to define the gradient of a function, which may only make sense in the case of manifolds, or of finitely generated groups.

Comment: A classical reference is a paper of David Jerison of 1986 in Duke Math Journal. But your measure is not smooth. Do you have an ideas for dealing with continuous or absolutely continuous measures? Lebesgue density point theorem? Is it enough for you to have the Poincaré inequality for small balls (radii $r$ smaller than some $R>0$)?

Comment: @iPe: if you have a notion of gradient for f.g. groups then it's likely to be extended to something in any compactly generated locally compact group.

Comment: @Nicolas: Let it be smooth then, but I do need it for large $R>0$.

Comment: @YCor: That's what motivated my question, but I'm having a little trouble with the formulation. Perhaps, since strictly speaking the gradient is not really need - only its integral is needed, one can somehow bypass the definition for gradient. For example, in Shalom & Tao's paper about a quantitative version of Gromov's theorem, they think of the gradient of a function as a multivariable function, but in fact don't really use it, because absolute value is always taken. I... I think I'm not being very clear...

Comment: A standard way to abstract "integral of the gradient" is with a [Dirichlet form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_form).

Comment: I thing that you can take the real line $R$ with the measure of density $x(1-x)\sin(1/x)^2$ or smomething of this type and prove that it does not satisfy a local Poincaré inequality. Maybe ``smooth'' is not the point. A Lipschitzian density is probably better.